# expand data.frame and insert average in another column

Tags: r, set

If the data set is

```
date        CPI  
2000/ 1     1.2 
2000/ 2     3.2
2000/ 3     1.6
```

then I want to get a weekly cpi

So this is my expected result.

```
date        CPI   Average
2000/ 1     1.2    0.3
2000/ 1     1.2    0.3
2000/ 1     1.2    0.3
2000/ 1     1.2    0.3
2000/ 2     3.2    0.8
2000/ 2     3.2    0.8
2000/ 2     3.2    0.8
2000/ 2     3.2    0.8
2000/ 3     1.6    0.4
2000/ 3     1.6    0.4
2000/ 3     1.6    0.4
2000/ 3     1.6    0.4
```

How Can I do this in R program?

please help me. my monthly Cpi is almost 200.

Answer (score 3):

May be this helps:

```
n <- 4
mydf1 <- transform(mydf, Average=CPI/n)       #created a new column `Average` by dividing CPI by n
mydf2 <-mydf1[rep(1:nrow(mydf1),each=n),]     #replicate the row numbers of the dataset `mydf1` by `n` and used the numeric index to expand the rows of `mydf1`
row.names(mydf2) <- 1:nrow(mydf2)             #change the rownames  
mydf2
#     date CPI Average
#1  2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
#2  2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
#3  2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
#4  2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
#5  2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
#6  2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
#7  2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
#8  2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
#9  2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#10 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#11 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#12 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
```

Or using `data.table`
Here, the idea is similar to the above.  First convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` using `setDT`.  Create a new column `Average:=CPI/n`.  Then use replicate `rep` the rownumbers of the dataset with `n` and use that numeric index to expand the rows of `mydf`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[mydf[, Average:=CPI/n][,rep(seq_len(.N), each=n)]]
#      date CPI Average
# 1: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
# 2: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
# 3: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
# 4: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
# 5: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
# 6: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
# 7: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
# 8: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
# 9: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#10: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#11: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
#12: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
```

If you need to separate the `date` in to `year` and `quarter` as shown in @KFB's post, you could use `cSplit` along with `data.table`.  In the below code, `setnames` are used to rename the columns after the `split`.  Rest of the procedure is the same as above.

Link to `cSplit` is https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733

```
 library(devtools)
 source_gist(11380733)
 DT1 <- setnames(cSplit(mydf, "date", '[/]', fixed=FALSE,direction='wide'), 
                           c("CPI", "year", "Quarter"))
  DT1[DT1[, Average:= CPI/n][,rep(seq_len(.N), each=n)]]
  #   CPI year Quarter Average
  #1: 1.2 2000       1     0.3
  #2: 1.2 2000       1     0.3
  #3: 1.2 2000       1     0.3
  #4: 1.2 2000       1     0.3
  #5: 3.2 2000       2     0.8
  #6: 3.2 2000       2     0.8
  #7: 3.2 2000       2     0.8
  #8: 3.2 2000       2     0.8
  #9: 1.6 2000       3     0.4
 #10: 1.6 2000       3     0.4
 #11: 1.6 2000       3     0.4
 #12: 1.6 2000       3     0.4
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(date = c("2000/ 1", "2000/ 2", "2000/ 3"), CPI = c(1.2, 
3.2, 1.6)), .Names = c("date", "CPI"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another data.table solution using @akrun's mydf:

```
mydt = data.table(mydf)
mydt2 = mydt[,data.table(apply(.SD,2,function(x) rep(x,4))),]
mydt2$CPI = as.numeric(mydt2$CPI)
mydt2[,Average:=CPI/4,]
mydt2
       date CPI Average
 1: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
 2: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
 3: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
 4: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
 5: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
 6: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
 7: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
 8: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
 9: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
10: 2000/ 1 1.2     0.3
11: 2000/ 2 3.2     0.8
12: 2000/ 3 1.6     0.4
```

Comment: Just a small note. Avoiding `apply` as much as possible would be nice, as it coerces the data.table to matrix.

Comment: @Arun: Thanks for the tip and best wishes for data.table package.